# Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process mod_wsgi in Centos7 with Cpanel/WHM

Tags: django, apache, sockets, mod-wsgi, whm

I'm with a problem while deploying `Django` in my VPS with `Centos 7.3` and WHM. It seems to work, except for a socket problem with `mod_wsgi`.

```
[Sun Jun 25 00:37:03.254774 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29756] (13)Permission denied: [client 66.249.83.220:35523] mod_wsgi (pid=29756): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'brunamaiahair.com.br' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.721.27.1.sock' as user with uid=1004.
```

I read to insert **WSGISocketPrefix** as a directive, so I edited `httpd.conf` and put:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi
```

But I'm receiving the same error. Here is the log with the modified `httpd.conf` after an Apache restart:

```
[Sat Jun 24 21:10:56.084269 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 721] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2k mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_wsgi/4.5.7 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Here is my `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess brunamaiahair.com.br socket-user=#1004 python-path=/home/bmhair/public_html/django/framework:/home/bmhair/public_html/django/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

WSGIProcessGroup brunamaiahair.com.br

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/bmhair/public_html/django/framework/framework/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 2):

See `socket-user` option in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

Recent CPanel installations seem to use `PrivilegesMode` set to `SECURE` so you will need to declare who should own the socket. It should be the user/uid Apache changes to when handling requests for you, rather than the default of the Apache user.

If for example the user which CPanel is setup to run your request as under Apache is `bmhair`, you need to add to the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive in the Apache configuration the option:

```
socket-user=bmhair
```

After a restart of Apache, check in the directory where the socket file is placed, eg., `/var/run/apache2` and check that socket file is owned by user `bmhair`.

Note that this will require that the directory `/var/run/apache2` provides access to other users, ie., not just `root` or the user Apache runs your code as. If that is not the case, then use `WSGISocketPrefix` to move the socket file to another directory which is accessible to the user `bmhair`. Generally you should not need to even override `WSGISocketPrefix` as the default location used is fine. If you had set it explicitly for some reason, and didn't allow the default to be used, that could also be part of the problem.

Comment: [root@srv ~]# cd /var/run/apache2
[root@srv apache2]# ls -lah
total 4,0K
drwx--x---  3 root   nobody  100 Jun 30 23:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root   root   1,4K Jul  1 00:02 ..
drwx------  2 nobody nobody   40 Jun 30 23:46 htcacheclean
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      4 Jun 30 23:46 httpd.pid
srwx------  1 bmhair root      0 Jun 30 23:46 wsgi.513.0.1.sock

Comment: my httpd.conf add this line
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2

Comment: So you can't use the directory ``/var/run/apache2`` as I mentioned, because the directory isn't accessible to non root user. For now try ``WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi``. It is not ideal using ``/tmp``, but should allow it to work.

Comment: Graham, thank you for you attention until now. My changes

edit httpd.conf, change to WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi
created a folder /tmp/wsgi and set onwner bmhair:bmhair and chmod 777

my: WSGIDaemonProcess brunamaiahair.com.br socket-user=bmhair python-path=/home/bmhair/public_html/django/framework:/home/bmhair/public_html/django/denv/lib/python2.7/site-packages

**log error**
: Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.541.0.1.sock' as user with uid=1013,`

Appears **WSGISocketPrefix** not effect in http global directive to change path

Comment: I did not say to create a directory ``/tmp/wsgi``. All I said was to add ``WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi``. The directory part in that is ``/tmp/``, the ``wsgi`` bit is a filename prefix. The directory you create isn't going to be used. If you still get the error about ``/var/run/apache2`` then you haven't put the ``WSGISocketPrefix`` directive in the correct place in the configuration file, or it is in a file that isn't being read. Best to stick it immediately after the existing ``LoadModule`` line for ``wsgi_module``.

Comment: Graham, one more time thanks. I follow your steps, and make this changes:

First I open/edit: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and add after LoadModule mod_wsgi: WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi, so I rebuild httpd and restart graceful server. But I'm receiving the same error: See the config

`Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi`

the error

`Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'brunamaiahair.com.br' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.527.0.1.sock' as user with uid=1013., referer: http://brunamaiahair.com.br/`

what I doing wrong?

Comment: The message says it isn't being set, or that setting is not being used as it still shows ``/var/run/apache2`` in the error message. Search very well through all the configuration files and make sure ``WSGISocketPrefix`` isn't being set somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The path /var/run/apache2 bmhair do not have access to that folder.Only root and approved users have.
So we need to show apache a path for wsgi socket.

- If it is VPS:

> WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

- If you are in a shared hosting:

> WSGISocketPrefix ../../var/run/wsgi

Or

> WSGISocketPrefix /home/bmhair/var/run/wsgi

As I can see you are in **bmhair** user so for you **2nd** one will work.

Comment: Why use a relative pathname over an absolute path name? If you use a relative path it may be resolved relative to Apache ``ServerRoot``, but don't guarantee that will work.

Comment: Our main intention should be showing a path for wsgi socket right.Cause the path Apache choosing for wsgi socket don't have access(/var/run/apache2).Thank you for the comment I will modify the answer like you said.